# Remove default white space document itext 7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

i use itext 7.1.9 for create the carrier lable bill.
i want my bill have full with and height of the document, i set with table 100 percent or large width but my document still have something like default padding, i want to remove it.
How can i do it.
This is my result

[image]

And i want to remove white space here

[image]

Here is my code

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Consider setting document margins to 0.

Comment: Please post code not images

Answer (score 1):

You can set the margins of a document by calling `setMargins(top, right, bottom, left)` on the document. Just pass all 0s for no margins.

Alternatively, you can set each margin individually with, for example, `setTopMargin(value)`.